# Levenshtein algorithm with custom character mapping

Tags: c#, algorithm, search, .net-3.5

I want to use Levenshtein algorithm to search in a list of strings. I want to implement a custom character mapping in order to type latin characters and searching in items in greek.

mapping example:

```
a = α, ά
b = β
i = ι,ί,ΐ,ϊ
... (etc)
u = ου, ού
```

So searching using `abu` in a list with

- αbu
- abού
- αού  (all greek characters)

will result with all items in the list. (item order is not a problem)

How do I apply a mapping in the algorithm? ([this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/toub/archive/2006/05/05/590814.aspx) is where I start)

Comment: The Levenshtein algorithm compares two strings based on an edit distance metric.  It typically defines a substitution rule which would seem to encompass what you are talking about.  Grab some sample code (sample code usually substitutes A-Z regardless of the character) and just replace this with your specific substitution rules.

Comment: @Jon How do I apply a mapping in the algorithm?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the best way would be to preprocess your symbols to one definite form (e.g. all in latin) and then use Levenshtein as you would do normaly.

In pseudocode:

```
int func(String latinStr, String greekStr) {
   String mappedStr = convertToLatin(greekStr); // e.g. now αβ would be ab 
   return Levenstein(latinStr, mappedStr);
}
```

And in `convertToLatin` you may symbol-by-symbol ask Dictionary with mappings for a replace and construct new string

Comment: The process you're referring to is called 'canonicalization'.